# Memory Leak issue : com.example.android.uamp.ui.FullScreenPlayerActivity has leaked

Tags: android, memory-leaks, exoplayer

I have been working on an music player app based on [android-UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) sample. And I have had installed LeakCanary to detect memory leak issue and find out that there is indeed a memory leak issue. Please be noted that I did not make any changes except adding the memory leak detection.

Please refer to the following information for details:

```html
In com.example.android.uamp:1.1:2.

com.example.android.uamp.ui.FullScreenPlayerActivity has leaked:
GC ROOT static android.os.UserManager.sInstance
references android.os.UserManager.mContext
references android.app.ContextImpl.mOuterContext
references com.example.android.uamp.MusicService.mConnections
references android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap.mArray
references array java.lang.Object[].[2]
references android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl.this$0
references android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler.mCallbackImpl
references android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi23.mBrowserObj
references android.media.browse.MediaBrowser.mContext
leaks com.example.android.uamp.ui.FullScreenPlayerActivity instance
Retaining: 631 KB.
Reference Key: 21cd0054-506d-4c6f-94d1-47090c16fbb0
Device: LGE google Nexus 5 hammerhead
Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.4-beta1 02804f3
Durations: watch=5024ms, gc=121ms, heap dump=6019ms, analysis=40029ms
```

You could also refer to the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6b4x1jib2r6cte/Dump_memory_Leak_UniversalMusicPlayer.hprof?dl=0) for the dump hprof file. To me it seems that this is a Android system bug? In this case, is there workaround? This is a deadly serious issue to my app as I could stably crash my app by exiting the app and entering the app again with playback on. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is better to raise this issue on their github repo. As you said, it could be a system associated leak and may help them fix it for all users!

Comment: Actually, I see you have already raised this issue there here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/75

Comment: Actually that is me. But nobody gets back to me. So I had thought come here for another try.

Answer (score 0):

Just for these who are still wondering about the question, it has been fixed in 23.3.0 Android support Library. Please refer to this [link](https://plus.google.com/u/2/113101937919336078298/posts/4VhBrayYaht) for more details.